# Artifactory cannot be installed as windows service

Tags: java, artifactory

I have Artifactory `artifactory-oss-6.10.1`, that I try to install as Windows service.

First problem I encounter is that the `installService.bat` has the lines

```
:gotJdkHome
if not exist "%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\java.exe" goto noJavaHome
if not exist "%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\javaw.exe" goto noJavaHome
```

I have JDK 12 installed and set as `JAVA_HOME`, but my JDK installation has no jre folder. I re-downloaded the jdk 12 from oracle, but the installation gives no jre folder

After I removed the `jre` path of the file, the installation fails due to a missing tomcat (?) (it just say that it cannot find the path).

So do I need to additionally install tomcat ? Because, when i simply start the `artifactory.bat`, Artifactory starts up.

So how can I install Artifactory as windows service ?

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this as well and managed to find a solution to get the service installed.

Open your InstallService.bat file. Locate the :gotJdkHome section. Remove \jre from the pathes like the following:

```
:gotJdkHome
if not exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" goto noJavaHome
if not exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe" goto noJavaHome
if not exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac.exe" goto noJavaHome
if not "%JRE_HOME%" == "" goto okJavaHome
set "JRE_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%"
```

Then you will be able to run the InstallService.bat and the service will be installed.

**But** you will not be able to launch the service because the JVM argument "java.endorsed.dirs" is not supported from Java 10.

You have to remove it from the following line in the bottom of the file:

```
"%EXECUTABLE%" //US//%SERVICE_NAME% --JvmOptions "-Dcatalina.base=%CATALINA_BASE%;-Dcatalina.home=%CATALINA_HOME%;-Djava.endorsed.dirs=%CATALINA_HOME%\endorsed" --StartMode jvm --StopMode jvm
```

in order to get

```
"%EXECUTABLE%" //US//%SERVICE_NAME% --JvmOptions "-Dcatalina.base=%CATALINA_BASE%;-Dcatalina.home=%CATALINA_HOME%" --StartMode jvm --StopMode jvm
```

Now your service will be able to start up.